# Is it possible for a moderator to handle flags on their own posts?

Tags: discussion, flags, moderators

If a moderator posts a question, answer, or comment that gets flagged, is it possible for that moderator to then handle those flags, or is there something in place to automatically prevent the conflict-of-interest?

Comment: When I first joined SO (a few years ago now) I complained about a moderator via a flag. I didn't even know what a moderator was, or that he was a mod and didn't realise he could see the flag! lol

Answer (score 50, accepted):

> is there something in place to automatically prevent the conflict-of-interest?

Nothing technical, but convention.

As part of moderator onboarding, they are told that whenever they face a conflict of interest (such as handling flags on their own posts/comments), they should get someone else, less partial to handle it.

Other than that, other moderators (and Stack Overflow staff) have access to post/comment histories, so these *can* be investigated in cases where a moderator may have indeed handled such flags themselves instead of deferring to others.

Moderators know they are accountable and that there isn't a place to hide in the system. They are also trusted users (trusted by the community, other moderators and Stack Overflow staff)—they are not likely to betray this trust.

Comment: If indeed someone would abuse his power/ you think a mod used his powers to aid himself/ put himself in a better position on the cost of others, you can post on meta about it. I think if theres any abuse of power, the (community-elected) mod will lose his status pretty fast.

Comment: And it might not be a conflict of interest if it's a custom flag for something completely unrelated.