# 2019 Stack Overflow Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

Stack Overflow is scheduled for its eleventh election [next week, March 4th](https://stackoverflow.com/election/11). In connection with that, we will be holding a Q&A with the candidates. This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.

> **The purpose of this thread was to collect questions for the questionnaire. The questionnaire is now live, and you may find it [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380885/2019-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire).**

As we've been doing in [previous years](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364152/2018-moderator-election-qa-question-collection), we're collecting questions one week in advance.

Here's how it'll work:

- Until the nomination phase, (so, until Monday, March 4th at 20:00:00Z UTC, or 3:00 pm EST on the same day, give or take some time to arrive), this question will be open to collect potential questions from the users of the site. Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates. Please only post *one question per answer*.
- We, the Community Team, will be providing a small selection of generic questions. The first two will be guaranteed to be included, the latter ones are if the community doesn't supply enough questions. This will be done in a single post, unlike the prior instruction.
- If your question contains a link, please use the syntax of `[text](link)`, as that will make it easier for transcribing for the finished questionnaire.
- This is a perfect opportunity to voice questions that are specific to your community and issues that you are running into at currently.
- Feel free to peruse the questionnaires from previous years: [2015](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289449/2015-moderator-election-qa-question-collection), [2015 round two](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309753/fall-2015-moderator-election-qa-question-collection), [2016](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337191/2016-stack-overflow-moderator-election-qa-question-collection), [2017](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351972/2017-moderator-election-qa-question-collection), [2018](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364152/2018-moderator-election-qa-question-collection)
- At the start of the nomination phase, the Community Team will select **up to 8 of the top voted questions submitted by the community** provided in this thread, to use in addition to the aforementioned 2 guaranteed questions.
- Once questions have been selected, a new question will be opened to host the actual questionnaire for the candidates, typically containing 10 questions in total.
- This is not the only option that users have for gathering information on candidates. As a community, you are still free to, for example, hold a live chat session with your candidates to ask further questions, or perhaps clarifications from what is provided in the Q&A.

If you have any questions or feedback about this process, feel free to post as a comment here.

Comment: Good luck to the future candidates!

Comment: Are we adding mods to the diamond force, or covering for mods that have left or will leave their positions?

Comment: 2 positions so probably just adding. 3 usually means a retirement

Comment: They never announce that until after the fact, @yivi.

Comment: I didn't see the horrible creative commons licence account dissociation question, at least.

Comment: I _demand_ to be nominated because the election is on my birthday.

Comment: You nominate yourself here, @Swordfish. Nominating others doesn't work out well, unless you've discussed with them in advance and gotten confirmation that they will accept. And, in that case, they can just nominate themselves.

Comment: I nominate @swordfish to be the next fall guy. Err I mean, moderator.

Comment: As a user who is not that active around here, I always admired the dedication of the candidates from each year. Good luck to everybody, not only in becoming a moderator, but also in being a good one!

Comment: There's something about the exhortation to "Please only post one question per answer." that makes my brain hurt

Comment: Why choose "*from 8 of the top voted questions*" ? Assuming this means "*from the 8 questions with the most up votes*", and not "*from 8 questions with enough up votes*", doesn't time have a major impact on this ? The 12 top voted have been posted on the first (and a few on the second) day of this poll. Why not make this so that questions are asked in first stage, and when the discussion is over (1 week or less just like this), have a real poll where votes are now independant of post time.

Comment: Because that puts more time, overhead, and emphasis into the process than is necessary. Elections are a big thing, in that moderation is important to the vitality and functionality of sites, so we want people to be present and attentive to it. But they're simultaneously *not* a big thing. For much the same reasons that we don't announce these months in advance to have people waffle on thinking about the process for a large period of time, we're not going to pile extra process to extend deliberation, timewise or otherwise, for the side Q&A.

Comment: There's actually a line missing, for some reason, that is in the earlier versions of this, but "We reserve some editorial control in the selection of the questions and may opt not to select a question that is tangential or irrelevant to moderation or the election." - it's within our process to examine all questions, not simply hit up the top 8 (excluding the preload) and just call it quits there. On some occasions across the network, we've had cause to skip over higher voted questions, or even just select 9-10 questions instead of just 8. It's a fluid process.

Comment: @GraceNote Fair enough. And thanks for pointing that out, I hadn't noticed !

Answer (score 143):

There is a high-rep user who is very active on the site, but frequently uses strong language which violates the [Stack Overflow Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) in their comments.

When you warned them, they replied stating that the questions are of low quality which is why they left those comments. They also threatened to quit the site.

Despite the warning, they continue to post similar comments. What steps, if any, will you take in order to address this situation?

What if the comments were on Meta instead of main? Does that change your approach at all?

Comment: That Won't happen again ...

Comment: Wait a minute...

Comment: So Bhargav, in a hypothetical response to this question, would the phrase containing the words, "...and don't let the door hit [you] on the way out" be something you'd consider "acceptable" or an ironic response?

Comment: While I've wanted to write that as a reply to a moderator message numerous times in the past, @Makoto, it certainly comes off as rude and unfriendly. It certainly is something which we don't write in moderator messages. (Also it isn't nice to ask someone to be-nice, when you're not nice :p)

Comment: Sure - I was half-joking.  There are ways to respond to that in a manner one wishes to without using specific, somewhat aggressive phrases.  If nothing else, if you *do* see responses using that kind of language, that'd give you some insight into how they'd handle those private moderator messages...

Comment: _"Be sure to gently close the door when you leave the premises."_ Same message, but not unfriendly ;-)

Comment: “We appreciate your wisdom, but it is also important for us that all our users feel safe to ask questions. As much as we appreciate your contributions, the damage caused by abusive language is greater.”

Comment: It seems to me that “strong language” is rather vague and could be interpreted several ways.  Do you mean cursing?  Demeaning?  Abrasive?  Blunt?  Direct?  ...etc...

Comment: @John, either cursing/abusive/demeaning or anything against the CoC.

Comment: @BhargavRao can you fill me in on what happened here?

Comment: @Jodast It is a hypothetical question, designed to test the response of moderator candidates. Don't read anything into it.

Comment: @CodyGray yeah but other comments are implying that this was an event that actually happened.

Answer (score 111):

A new, low-rep user asks a non-duplicate, non-trivial, on-topic question **on Meta**. For unclear reasons, the question is met with downvotes and a pile-on of comments from multiple users. The question gets closed, and some comments get flagged.

You have a pretty good idea of what an answer to said question would look like.

What steps, if any, would you take to turn this situation around for the benefit of all parties?

Comment: Why do you want to make sure that the close-voters who did wrong to the question get away unharmed?

Comment: @Bergi I imagine answers reveal if the candidates have a de-escalate or an enforcement type of style on meta. We could also learn if they consider handing out a ban a way of "harming" users. I don't (yet) have to answer my own question ...

Comment: I don't think moderators can solve meta-bandwagon behavior. At the point in time you describe, the damage has already been done. There's not really a way to save it or untangling it. Deleting the whole disaster it probably the best course.

Comment: You have my vote @Lundin ... you have my vote ...

Comment: @rene I can't even tell if you are being sarcastic or if "delete the whole mess" was the answer you were actually looking for.

Comment: @Lundin I prefer to keep my cards close to my chest and I'm hardly ever sarcastic ;). As I said before: I don't need to answer my own question but I encourage you to nominate yourself because I'm eager to learn your extended answer, assuming this one ends up in the mod questionnaire.

Comment: I'm probably the least suitable person around, so I'll pass on that...

Answer (score 87):

Write a [Haiku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haiku) poem that catches the essence of why you think it will be fun to handle 400 flags every day.

<sup>If you don't like Haiku feel free to use any another form of poetry or a bullet list to express how you will survive the "grind", but keep it very short!</sup>

Comment: *100 x day is probably already a good deed, but lets push it some*

Comment: *Flags are coming in, Brad Larson is not here now, Time to earn that [hat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299484/what-is-this-strange-diamond-logo-on-my-stack-exchange-cap)*

Comment: All the flags are gone / cleaning up the site is hard / but I love it so

Comment: This looks like a joke at first, but it's actually a deceptively good question. Forces a short answer to a very important part of moderation here.

Comment: @Undo When we're limited to 8 community questions, I'd rather not have this can-a-fish-climb-a-tree test as one of them. It'd be much better if it were just "describe succinctly why you think running for mod is a good idea" rather than assuming candidates 1) are good at writing poetry, or 2) doing this because it's fun.

Comment: You don't need to be good at writing poetry to write a Haiku @tyler... Also, a candidate can clearly start with "I am not good at poetry, so I will write down a paragraph about why I will not burn out while handling 400 flags per day:"

Comment: @BhargavRao That just underscores the uselessness of posting this as one of the *very limited* number of questions to be presented to candidates.

Comment: @TylerH, I don't see it that way. It does seem like an important question. There are moderators who do burn out. Moderators on Microsoft forums suffer from PTSD. If a candidate cannot handle the pressure of being a moderator, then they probably shouldn't be standing for an election.

Comment: Also, if a candidate is able to recognize the underlying question in this post, then I'm sure that that person would be able to understand most of the recent meta questions.

Comment: @BhargavRao I agree it's a useful question. The bad part is that it's imposing some silly restriction that serves as a distraction and might cause noise in the voting process all due to what's essentially a joke. "I like that guy's haiku better because <insert non-policy reason here>". if you wanna know why someone is running for moderator... just ask them why. I don't want to read haikus and I don't care about moderators' ability to write them.

Comment: @TylerH, if the electorate are gullible enough to be misled by just a haiku, then they probably aren't good enough to take decisions. Also does removing this one question from the list prevent the candidates from adding witty sentences in their post? In fact, this would generalize them all by making everyone include something that is amusing to read. FWIW, I do prefer moderators who like to enjoy themselves while moderating, rather than just be a rule following robot. If it interests you, feel free to post a paraphrase of this answer in plain English.

Comment: And regarding your edit, if you don't want to read haikus, then please don't. As I mentioned already, if the candidates prefer to add it as a paragraph, then they can. We are not forcing every candidate to write poems, nor are we deleting their posts just because they couldn't.

Comment: How about a compromise: say that candidates *don't* have to write a haiku if they don't feel comfortable writing one, and just keep it short in general. The last thing we want candidates to do is stress out over not being able to fit their thoughts and reasoning into a 5-7-5 syllable format and potentially not even post an answer as a result.

Comment: I sincerely hope this is not included in the mod questionnaire, no matter how many upvotes it has. The premise of handling 400 flags a day is incorrect and the haiku is totally irrelevant to moderation.

Comment: Needs a limerick alternative. "There was a young mod from Boston / who tracked all the spammers but lost one..."

Comment: This is why the site is going to the dogs. Too many mods are artistically insensitive haiku-hating slobs who can’t hack a mere 400 flags a day! /s

Comment: Needs to be deleted. "There once was a meta poster, that brought out all the poets and posers. In an election no doubt, it had such clout, that they elected all the clowns and circus performers."

Comment: @YvetteColomb I propose not only new candidates but also sitting mods write a haiku. Lowest voted sitting mod gets de-modded ... let the chaos start ...

Comment: @rene I see your proposal and raise you one. I propose we put all the existing mods and all the candidates into a huge dome... :D

Comment: A seasoned and wise moderator / Hails from the East - Singapore / "I quite like to rhyme / though not all the time / but to force it is to be a bore."

Comment: @YvetteColomb I'm sorry to see that you missed the idea of the question focusing on Haiku and 400, I have edited some and will clarify the idea behind this question. The *400* was just a "random" number (pushing it some, see my first comment), but we do elect moderators to handle flags, handling flags can be fun for a couple of days, weeks but we would expected you to do it for years. There this crud reality of all these darn flags that a moderator wakes up to everyday. Why Haiku, I wanted to keep it short and also give the candidates a possibility to draw attention to post. *continue*

Comment: Reading through nominations posts can be boring specially if questions are the same as previous year, it's often a reiteration of same thing. Hence I wanted the candidate to have the possibility to write/start their answer with an "ad" something more "artistic" but still relevant. Something that would make the nomination post draw more general attention. Now I have edited to specify that you do not need to use Haiku, but actually I taught any mod candiate would feel free to not use it anyway .

Comment: @BoltClock I have edited the post to explicitly give more artistic freedom, but probably any candiate ignoring the Haiku requirement using a bullet list would have only showed guts!

Comment: @PetterFriberg I hate fun. Now get off my lawn you whipper snappers. *waving newspaper* :D

Comment: POETRY! Yes! I won't be happy until all posts on Stack Overflow consist entirely of rhyming couplets. Seriously though, I'd be slightly worried that this may be much harder for non native English speakers.

Comment: "A giant mass of unhandled flagging / is causing the moderators table to be sagging / I'll robo review / until I empty the queue / and wonder why my election campaign's support is lagging" - Note:  I'm obviously not actually planning to run, but felt the urge to be silly and couldn't come up with anything better on the spur of the moment.

Comment: @DavidG Let the Poetry Wars begin old -fiend- friend :D

Comment: Poetry?! Man, I never would have been elected moderator if there was poetry involved. And *keep it short*? Wow, you really are trying to find my opposite.

Comment: _Flags gently falling from the sky - Like cherry blossoms in spring - Life returns to barren queues_. Seriously though, we might as well ask mod candidates to post their favourite cat picture.

Comment: Don't let the candidate mods commit *sudoku* over **haiku**.

Comment: // , Definitely downvote this one, because we must purge StackOverflow of even the feeblest attempts at humor.

Comment: I like the honesty in this question. Because "moderator" really is mostly a flag-janitor if I have to believe some [amusing meta posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166623/what-is-a-day-in-the-life-of-a-stack-exchange-moderator-like) :)

Comment: I don't care for poetry, but _How will you survive the grind?_ is the only relevant question for any aspiring moderator.

Comment: Poet I am not; none shall ever vote for me, I am not concise.

Answer (score 77):

A chat room has taken to an undesirable topic (not necessarily ban-worthy, but something that Stack Overflow chat is not meant to discuss).

A new user has entered the room and begins mass-flagging anything they consider bad and demanding the conversation stop by threatening more flags. Regulars in the room counter-flag the new user's threats.

How would you handle this?

Comment: Just curious: Is this scenario purely hypothetical, or has it been known to happen before?

Comment: @StephenKennedy Maybe not that extreme but [this might give background](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357749/request-for-reopening-the-room-android-era-with-kotlin-and-java/357755#357755)

Comment: @StephenKennedy I loosely based it on [this incident](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366793/2370483) (I added a lot more drama to this Q), but there have been [other](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311540) [incidents](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10914/how-come-our-main-chat-mos-eisley-got-frozen-this-time) where chat got out of hand and moderators (or CMs) were needed.It's a roundabout way about asking what a potential mod would do with an unruly chat room.

Comment: Good question. Chat rooms often take exception to mods stepping in to moderate, particularly if the mod isn't a regular in that room.

Comment: It's a good question because candidates might not even be aware that they are responsible for those swamps... I mean rooms, as well.

Comment: There is a higher expectation of behavior in chat rooms which are 'officially' named after a specific (language) tag, since those regulate what goes on in that tag on SO. Occasionally, room owner behavior is a cause of unruliness. Regulating this is a gray area on SO.

Answer (score 67):

A user habitually flags old comments as being in violation of our Code of Conduct ("unfriendly or unkind" and/or "harassment, bigotry, or abuse"), which can lead to disciplinary action against the original commenter. In your judgment, the flagged comments are on the borderline of rude.

What do you do?

Comment: This is actually a relevant issue faced by mods.

Comment: I don't get the purpose of this question? I'd say "delete the comment", but it looks like you're focusing on the person who casts the flag. Is this about providing feedback to them?

Comment: @Adriaan that's the purpose of the question. What do you do? It's to test the knowledge of candidates. On many levels it's a loaded question. Helpful unkind flags carry consequences.

Comment: @YvetteColomb I mentioned they didn't under another answer here... can you clarify what the penalty is for getting several of your comments flagged as unkind/rude?

Comment: @TylerH Too many helpful unkind or rude/abusive flags raise an auto more flag for too many abusive comments. The mod then reviews the comment and account history. A decision is made whether to send a mod message and possibly suspend.

Comment: @YvetteColomb `... helpful unkind or rude/abusive flags...` **if** they are actually helpful. And not just spamming a user as being to be considered (very arbitrarily) "rude".

Answer (score 52):

An established user (say > 6 years tenure, > 10k reputation, > 100 posts) has developed a tendency to ask low-quality questions (*e.g.*, debugging help without MCVE, too broad "write my project", POB security issues, etc). These low-quality questions are closed by the community, and comments are left suggesting ways to improve. The user does not heed this advice, and continues to ask poor questions.

The automatic question ban won't kick in, since their old posts attract a few upvotes each week. As a moderator, is this something you should take action on, or something you should leave to the community to handle? If you do take action, what would you do?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by mediocre questions here? AFAIK there's no problem with 'mediocre' questions... what matters is whether they're on-topic. Why would a moderator need to do anything here? Not all questions can be great.

Comment: @TylerH The alleged problem emerges when that user can continue asking poor questions, whereas a newer user would have been question banned. It can be perceived as having double standards in favor of users who have collected a lot of reputation over time, usually in the days when the bar of quality was indeed lower.

Comment: @E_net4 OK, well Adriaan didn't say "poor" questions. He said "mediocre". A mediocre question should have no problems... but should not be particularly interesting or remarkably well-researched, either. Again, clarification on that is needed, because there's no inherent problem with mediocre questions. Even if he meant "poor", instead, clarification is still needed. What about it is poor? The effort by the OP? The spelling and grammar? Or something worse like the lack of an MCVE or the fact that it's POB/Too Broad/a dupe?

Comment: @TylerH It is known that some people uphold higher expectations from established users, so the phrasing here doesn't seem surprising to me. That is a fair distinction nonetheless.

Comment: This can happen through random chance, a user posts a question which happens to become incredibly popular +1000s. Reputation doesn't always imply ability to ask high quality questions nor a deep understanding of how the site works.

Comment: @TylerH I indeed meant what E_net4 has said: questions which would be closed. I have seen this happen with several >10k users who got their rep from 8, 9 yo Qs, and now ask questions which are broad/don't have an MCVE/are POB etc. Why they ask these I have no idea, but closing them doesn't help them to improve their question standard, and since the question ban won't kick in, there's no way to get them to improve from a normal user's side. Hence the question

Comment: I don't get why moderators need to be involved in this, the community is perfectly able to handle it on its own. After getting down voted/close voted frequently enough, the user will fall in line.

Comment: I've seen this happen within the past few months, an 8k user (most of that rep attained from questions asked c. 2010) returns after a 6 year hiatus and asks a series of very poorly-worded and poorly-formatted questions, the sort of thing that would get a new user question-banned very quickly. But because of those historic questions that ban will never come.

Comment: They are like "made guys", other users don't dare criticize them.

Comment: @Lundin I have personally seen this with the user not falling in line.

Comment: @Lundin: LOL! Wishful thinking. No, some of these people are very stubborn and very unwilling to improve. Seen it first hand. And they've got so much rep that they can put a bounty on all their questions, making it impossible to close them for another week. If you live in smaller tags it sometimes takes a while to close a bad question, long enough to allow a bounty to be placed.

Comment: Sounds like an issue for the community, not moderators

Comment: Are you saying that they are actually the same **Users** coming back or just same **User IDs**?  What you describe smells like an account take-over.

Comment: @PM77-1 same userID for certain; we (and even mods can't) determine the other. Not necessarily an account take over though. Tool-rec and overly broad 'how to git' questions gained massive voted back in 2010. Same user asking similar questions now just has not adjusted to the tightened scope of SO.

Comment: There’s a good question hidden in here, and it’s the one that came out in comments: is this something you as a moderator should take action on, or something you should leave entirely to the community to handle? Asking about the specific message you’d send them isn’t a great question. There’s a standard message template for consistently low-quality contributions, so that’d be any moderators’ standard go-to choice, unless there was a compelling reason to take extreme action, and that’s not assumed in this scenario.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Given that I have barely ever seen the phenomenon described in 8 years as a member... then yes, wishful and realistic thinking, as it must be very rare.

Comment: @Lundin: You follow the C and C++ tags. Try following a small tag for a while. I've been here a little over a year, and have seen several cases like this (including one extreme case, a user posting several terrible questions a week, for two months in a row, and complaining on Meta about the poor reception he was getting).

Comment: @CrisLuengo There's barely anyone getting high rep from such tags so I actually doubt it.

Answer (score 51):

Here is a set of general questions, gathered as very common questions asked every election. As mentioned in the instructions, the first two questions are guaranteed to show up in the Q&A, while the others are if there aren't enough questions (or, if you like one enough, you may split it off as a separate answer for review within the community's 8).

- How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
- How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

---

- In your opinion, what do moderators do?
- A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
- In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Comment: I was going to add a question similar to the last one. Now I don't have to. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Grace. Which of the three optional examples will be taken if this answer goes to top 6?

Comment: Although a bit open ended, I do like "In your opinion, what do moderators do?" .. perhaps it could be frame and expressed differently: given (these common moderator tasks enumerated; or these questions you've previously answered): in your opinion, what do [Stack Overflow] moderators do?

Comment: in regards to what @iBug related though, is this an ordered list of optional questions?  I think you should have probably expressed these in your topic post above, but I'm going to presume all of these upvotes are for "what do moderators do?" and notions of the other two questions are (or otherwise, would have been) expressed in separate questions :D

Answer (score 47):

Moderators are not selected because they are domain experts in certain tags, but it so happens that you are an expert in one such tag.  You see that several members of the community have elected to close a question as a duplicate, but you see that the duplicates don't actually answer the question as stated, nor do they provide a useful signpost for the asker.  How do you proceed?

Comment: Do you mean a hasty, dismissive close-as-dupe (which is quite common)? Or downright abuse, or brigade close-voting (which are rarer)? I think the answer depends on user motivations, whether the same users keep doing the same thing, and how offtopic/rude the close target is.

Comment: Um...it doesn't really matter @smci - you see, irrespective of motive, a question which is closed as a dupe which you can objectively prove *isn't* a dupe.  Moderators typically do not step into this foray because they're not SMEs on every language out there, nor do we want them to be, but it is the case that some *are*.  Knowing how candidates would deal with this circumstance to the betterment of the site would be nice to learn.

Answer (score 44):

This is a favorite of mine [from the last year](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/364156/4099593):

> Are there any meta posts which you are not proud of? In other words, if you ever ask a meta post, and it receives a lot of negative feedback, what would you do? (Would you ask for it to be dissociated from your account?)

Comment: I prefer this to the typical, what are you proud of. It's more of a challenge to answer.

Comment: @YvetteColomb, What makes it more challenging to answer in your opinion and why does that make it a better question to ask ?

Comment: to me, "What are you proud of" seems like more of a challenge to answer, yea. It's a broader context.  @Mat I think "it" was meant to be "the typical [question]" in Yvette's comment. Your question of the comparison is still valid, but I suspect you probably wouldn't have invoked reasoning if you interpreted "it" to mean "the typical [question]"

Comment: To me it reads: "I prefer this (what are you *not* proud of) to the typical (what are you proud of). It's (the former) more of a challenge to answer." Please correct me if I misunderstood

Answer (score 35):

Can you highlight some of your posts **on Meta** that have been received poorly, and describe what information you've gleaned as a result of those discussions/experiences?

Comment: ...and if you're not active on Meta, don't you think you should be if you want to be a mod? ;)

Comment: You would be *stunned* at the applicants who don't really have a presence here on meta, @JoshCaswell.

Comment: Yes, I have indeed been in the past.

Comment: Tbh, "lack of Meta discussion" never struck me as one of the most pressing issues of this site. A relatively low volume of Meta participation in itself would not be huge deal in my eyes.

Comment: @JoshCaswell If I may use myself as an example, I read meta most days, and discuss meta-topics in the chat rooms daily, but only have 9 posts here. I have most of the moderation badges and 8k helpful flags. I know how the site works. Why would my low meta post count have any bearing at all on my ability to moderate given these other statistics? [Hypothetical; I am not a potential candidate].

Comment: @StephenKennedy:  I'd argue that Meta participation correlates to site and policy participation.  *Knowing* the policies that we decide on Meta is important.  *Participating* in how those policies get shaped and formed, doubly so.  Additionally, chat can be fairly inaccessible (e.g. no mobile support, not clear exactly *which* room you're discussing these things in, as they are **legion**), whereas the main Meta site has everything in one neat little package.  It gives me some kind of peace to know that a candidate at least participates here, too.

Comment: Reasonable question, @StephenKennedy; perhaps I was too glib. I wouldn't count a low number of actual posts against a candidate, as long as they seemed to have familiarity with the stuff that comes up here. "Participation" in a "reads the newspaper and is conversant" sense is the important thing to me.

Comment: Case in point: me. I had 12 answers on meta when I became a moderator, but I had nearly a thousand comments. I used to be quite active in commenting and voting, but never thought that I had to answer posts because I knew that there were lots of meta-heads who would bring out what I wanted to say in a better way. So, "active on meta" is something which is necessary, "actively posting on meta" might not be.

Comment: Posting on *language-specific things* on Meta is often a waste of time or counterproductive; the lack of tag rep requirement means a Meta dweller (or clueless high-rep user from other unrelated tags) can shove their oar in on Meta discussions which they don't even understand, without consequence. This will continue to be an antipattern on Meta until there is an ability to optionally set minimum tag rep to participate in a tag-specific discussion. There is a gap in SO's capabilities for posting on something that's specific to multiple tags, i.e. wider than one specific tag.

Comment: What does any of that have to do with my question @smci?

Comment: @Makoto: that Meta is not the land of milk and honey, it's mainly good for totally language-/tag-agnostic questions. There's no ideal place for issues spanning several languages or tags; neither Meta nor chatrooms. So: do the candidates have structural improvement suggestions for Meta? (yes I know they're not required to be tag experts)

Comment: @smci:  Sorry, still not seeing how this has to do with the question I'm posing *here*.

Comment: This is a direct rephrase of the question you're asking here. Because it would be weird for a user to engage with Meta much and come away with anything other than a strong awareness of its limitations for the types of questions that can be usefully asked - rather than the user's own personal limitations. I see many high-rep users talk dismissively about questions, without realizing that sometimes their lack of knowledge in a specific tag or domain, and the lack of a rep threshold, means their actions are actively destructive to Meta and SO. So I'm curious to see if candidates acknowledge that.

Answer (score 27):

From a [previous election](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/309847/3956566), but still relevant.

A user flags a post or comment as rude or offensive to a minority group, or as a member of a minority group. You know little about the issues facing this minority group and the post would not be offensive to the majority of users.

What do you do?

Answer (score 23):

In your own words, what role do diamond moderators play with the Welcoming drive, and what can be done to make that role more valuable for beginners and veterans alike?

Comment: Yep the welcoming drive started after the last election, so coming into this election we're facing a shift in the expectation of the site's rules and culture.

Comment: The second half of the question seems to provide a leading answer to the first half. Otherwise, I think this is a great subject to ask about.

Answer (score 11):

As a frequent, low-rep user of this site, I am pretty interested in knowing what the general motivation of the people running it is, and what they think their contribution will and should be, according to how **they** specifically believe would be best for the community. With that in mind <sup><sub>(and [rene's question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/364160/6923568) from 2018)</sub></sup>, here is a more general question:

- Given your views of what Stack Overflow's (Main and Meta) goals are at this point in time, what moderating actions will you mainly focus on and why will/should that move the site toward those goals (or keep things as they are) ?

Comment: The original question says "*Please only post one question per answer.*" - presumably so each  can be voted on *individually*. Perhaps you could split your answer into two - one question per answer (or conflate your questions into one)?

Comment: @WaiHaLee Lemme see if I can correctly merge both, Thanks

Comment: As insteresting as the more scenario-based questions are, do you guys not think it's valid/important to ask about future mods' general intentions ? Yes, they'll probably spend most of their time checking flags, but on the long run, should they not have some sort of defined objective ?

Comment: I think this is a *great* opening question: "Why are you running? What are your goals? How will handing you a diamond help the site?"

Answer (score 10):

Suppose a user frequently posts comments criticising others in a way that some users - including you - consider abrasive and insulting. You message this user asking them to tone it down, and suggest some examples of ways they could've phrased their recent comments more nicely. However, the user disagrees with your assessment. Their previous comments were blunt but not rude, they argue. What you read as abrasiveness and personal insult is really, they tell you, nothing but respectful professional candor. In fact, *your* proposed style is the rude one - it's patronising and saccharine, and comes across like talking down to a child. They would not be comfortable, they tell you, posting comments in the tone that you want them to, because that tone is horribly rude.

You don't share their sensibilities, and you're sure that at least some of the community are on your side - this user has been attracting flags, and you agree that the flagged comments are often pretty obnoxious. But you also believe that the user is sincere in their belief that their style of writing is polite, and that they have a genuine conscientious objection to changing to a style that, to them, would amount to pointlessly insulting other people.

How do you proceed?

Comment: Asking for a friend.

Answer (score 8):

As a regular on main and meta you have existing preconceptions about users and groups of users, not all of them positive. Are you worried that these preconceptions might affect the way you will handle corresponding flags? How do you think you can ensure that this does not happen so that you will wield your new powers objectively?

Answer (score 6):

Your comments towards a user exhibiting misbehavior, despite your best intentions, went wrong. The user only lashed out at you, continuing to post inappropriate and unfriendly comments while calling you a bad person. Would you consider it to be a [conflict of interest](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338469/1233251) if you were to handle this user yourself (as in, remove the comments and record this incident into their history)?

Comment: Afaik, moderators already have quite strict guidelines in handling with cases like these.

Comment: @Cerbrus Hope to have a mod clarify that if so. I have seen more than one case of comments towards moderators not being cleaned up. If there is such a strict guideline, it is nonetheless a tricky situation that the candidates may have varying opinions on, so they could still be handling the situation in slightly different ways, albeit confirming to the same set of rules. All I found on the subject so far was the linked question.

Comment: @Cerbrus, there is no strict guidelines, just in our ethics. The ethical code of mods dictates to not handle posts where they have a CoI. There are many different cases of CoI, and usually all mods adhere to this unwritten guidelines.

Comment: You seem to be driving at something quite specific here, and I don’t think it makes for a good general moderator candidate question. If you think we should have clearer policies on conflicts of interest, that’s a separate Meta discussion, and then all moderators should follow that consensus. If you’ve had a negative experience, then you should take that up with the individual(s) involved in a separate Meta post.

Answer (score -5):

Often, users leave comments criticising answers - for example, by pointing out factual inaccuracies, the existence of a superior solution, or security issues or violations of best practice in the code in the answer.

Since such comments are, by nature, attacks on the quality of someone else's work, it is inevitable that they will frequently upset the answerers that they are directed at. Such upset may or may not be exacerbated by the comment's tone; such comments are often a bit more abrasive, patronising, or condemnatory than they need to be. (And sometimes, of course, they're just outright, undeniably rude.)

How will you handle flags on such comments? I posit that decisions about whether to delete them are a balancing act between maintaining civility and allowing criticisms to remain visible for the benefit of future readers; is that a real tradeoff, or a flawed perspective? If the tradeoff is real, which side will you tend to err on?

Comment: Although this is a common thing, I do not see how it would help screening; what else can someone answer other than "If the comments are rude, I will send a 'Be nice' mod message". Seems too hypothetical imo.

Comment: @Mat I disagree and think there are lots of things mods could reasonably have different views on here. Should an abrasively-worded comment that contains an important criticism be deleted? Is it important that criticisms be "constructive" in the narrow sense that they are aimed at causing the post being criticised to be edited to resolve the issue, or is that not a requirement? Given that criticism is to some degree an inherently unfriendly act, how do you walk the line between allowing criticism and enforcing the ban on unfriendly language? Is plain blunt criticism inherently problematic?

Comment: I think your questions are legitimate, but I truly feel they can all be summarized as "Where do you draw the line in terms of rude behavior". No amount of good criticism excuses rude content; the answers will need to make up scenarios and that can I believe is not a good screening method. I prefer your other question.

Comment: that I believe***

Comment: I disagree with the premise "Since such comments are, by nature, attacks on the quality of someone else's work." [Attack](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/attacking) can refer to starting an offensive, blaming, abusing, beginning hostilities, or other aggressive behavior. All of these can be done in a comment, however, *criticism* in and of itself is not necessarily an attack. Take this comment for example; I am criticizing your answer, but I am in no sense of the word attacking you or your work.

Comment: @DavyM as always, what is offensive, blaming, abusing, beginning hostilities, or other aggressive behavior is in the eye of the beholder.

Answer (score -7):

How effective are you with the tools you have at your disposal right now?

Please tell us: how many close votes and delete votes did you cast in the first two months of 2019? How many helpful flags did you raise, and how many reviews did you complete in each queue? What is your median for all of the above?

Comment: How would one find this information out? As far as I can tell I'd need to figure out how many pages to go back before I'm one year in the past, then multiply by the number of items per page.

Comment: @WaiHaLee This year started just about 8 weeks ago, so not too much work. I'll clarify.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Oops, misread. Some totals are presented, but some actions on deleted items are not visible for example. I'm asking for a clearer, more detailed breakdown.

Comment: How about "*In January and February 2019, .....*"? By the time the nominations are open it'll be March and it'll be the same 59 day period for every user.

Comment: @WaiHaLee Fine with me.

Comment: FWIW candidates already have a link to the reviews tab of their profile in the nomination user card, so we can already see how many reviews they've done in each queue. Them answering this question would save us one click per candidate each.

Comment: @TylerH That was Josh's point as well, which he deleted for some reason. Quoting myself for reference: "Some totals are presented, but some actions on deleted items are not visible for example. I'm asking for a clearer, more detailed breakdown."

Comment: Won't we get most of this information from the context of the "Moderation score"?

Comment: @TylerH - not all reviews show (for me, at least) in the 'all actions/reviews', such as those in the Low Quality Posts queue.

Comment: @Makoto Not really. That a) just counts rep and badges, thus missing several of the items I ask about and b) does not discern between recent activity and a candidates action of, say, years. For example, I still have 40/40 mod score, but this question would easliy expose my lack of commitment in recent times.

Comment: Sure, but I'm confused as to the value of it.  Are you looking for someone who can handle flags, or is a robot?  Help me paint a picture here.

Comment: @Makoto I'm looking for someone who is actually going to handle flags. Thus, I want to see they are using the tools they currently have available to at least a large extend. A lot of people _could_ be good mods in the sense that they are able to correctly judge a flag, but well... If every single elected mod actually put in their 30 min a day, we probably would not be having an election right now.

Comment: Now whether the extra information that would come from this is worth one of the eight slots is a matter of opinion, of course. Votes will tell.

Comment: I'm not trying to be facetious, but I do maintain that we'll establish a decent amount from the "Moderator score" metric that comes out with candidates.  I've found in the past that said score can leave a bad taste in my mouth with someone who *does* get elected but doesn't feel like a good moderator.  I won't disagree that handling flags is important, but at the same time, I'm not convinced that numbers *alone* would tell us anything meaningful about *how* they handle those flags.

Comment: @Makoto Well no, but this question is not about the quality of a candidates judgment, but strictly about the quantity. Other questions and metrics will focus on the former, and that's important. However, I'd prefer to give my vote to someone who is actually going to use their vetted judgment. Quantity matters, too.

Comment: *”If every single elected mod actually put in their 30 min a day, we probably would not be having an election right now.”* That’s not true. The flag queue is regularly so low that moderators are essentially playing [speed](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_(card_game)) against each other in trying to handle flags. So, we actually do have room for moderators on the team that want to focus on issues other than flag-handing. That said, I do *really* like what this “What have you done with the tools you have?” question gets at. “Why do you want a bigger shovel?”, basically.

Comment: @CodyGray Can't say for sure from my POV of course, but the queue seems literally exceptionally fast atm. Maybe you too noticed longer handling times in the past year. Also, this situation can change quickly when a [not so huge subset of mods](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351972/2017-moderator-election-qa-question-collection#comment491101_351974) becomes busy with other stuff in life. Anyway, yes, the "bigger shovel" is the gist of the question, and better wording than mine probably.

Answer (score -8):

How will you handle flags on "idownvotedbecau.se" links?

We've been told that [if we use these links pejoratively, we can get suspended](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/379603/812149). How will you distinguish between users using these links pejoratively, and users using these to help?

You don't want to let a bully run free. But you don't want to suspend a well-meaning user unfairly, either.

A question may need improvement on multiple issues. One user might point out that the asker posted an [image of their code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode), another might note that the asker hasn't provided [details of their Exception](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails). Both improvements are required to make the question suitable for Stack Overflow. How will you determine if the commenters are trying to help, or if they are just jerks piling on?

Comment: [I thought we already established this.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356051/1079354)  It isn't like moderators suspend for *one* comment unless that comment was *really* offensive or bad, y'know.

Comment: @Makoto That's from 2017, but Tim Post's answer that I linked is from this year . In between we've had the Welcoming blog and the CoC changes. I'm interested in learning how the moderator candidate is going to judge if these links are used pejoratively or not.

Comment: This is *way* too specific of a question to justify putting on a top-10 list. If you want to know what a candidate's stance is on pejorative comments, then ask about that. Being a single-issue voter is silly enough, and when that single issue is one's feelings on idownvotedbecau.se comments, it's even sillier.

Comment: @CodyGray Please don't conclude from a single question that I'm a single-issue voter on SO moderator elections. I'll think about a question on where the candidate stands regarding comments under the new CoC- but don't hold your breath; I've got a busy week ahead.

Answer (score -9):

Consider the [case](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/365691/2675154),
where a user flags an answer that appears to be [spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58032/294055),
because the post doesn't disclose the author's affiliation with a recommended non-free product.

The answer is a few years old and the author hasn't posted any similar answers (i.e. spam) since then.

The answered question itself appears to be off-topic (asking for an off-site resource).

How do you act on the flag, the answer, and the question?

Comment: An edge case is if a users advocates a service or product of a company that they didn't previously work at but do now, does that render their previous answer as spam?

Comment: This is not a rare occurrence, it's a good question.

Answer (score -9):

You find a high-rep user's comments are being flagged as rude/abusive by a disgruntled user over a short period of time. The comments in question cover a period of 10 years, so this is clearly a form of targeting. Using objective criteria they are almost all rude, but cover a large period of time and a small percentage of high-rep user's contribution to the site.

What, if any, action do you take apart from marking the flags as helpful?

Comment: This is a fair question in general, but I'm not sure it's particularly useful as a screening question. There are standard guidelines for how to deal with this, and it would only be in *very* unusual cases that any moderator would do something out of the ordinary. The typical response would be to send one of the canned "please be nice" moderator messages to the user who was flagged (unless the flags were *completely* spurious).

Comment: @CodyGray, Sure. I mean, this happened in real life. And what happened there was the *flagger* was publicly demonized (by mods as well as other users). So, no, it's not clear cut.

Comment: @jpp I'd be interested in a link to the case where this happened previously?

Comment: @MarkAmery, This [highly upvoted comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365937/why-is-this-comment-not-considered-rude#comment573736_365937), and associated posts/comments.

Answer (score -19):

There is a say "A leader is one who makes sure no leader is needed at all".

What efforts or tools would you use for automating stuff like grammar checks, process flows, post tone alerts (rude/acceptable etc)?

Because a machine can do better, unbiased review in the above areas than a human moderator, as a lot has changed with NLP/Data science.

Comment: I can't see how this would be a useful question to be asked of a candidate moderator? There's already community and some experimental site stuff to detect these kinds of things but AI is far from having the ability to dealing with people and their relationships (good/bad) on a site.

Comment: @JonClements I feel a moderator time is more valuable than using on the above tasks. e.g as I write these lines,  Grammarly(a tool) does the grammar check .. likewise, AI can classify any post overall tone(positive/negative) also without any human intervention.

Comment: Your tool isn't doing a great job of capitalising sentences? Nor can any tool that exists right now evaluate what a comment really means in context? Was someone just having a bad day and made a stupid outburst... are two/more users having a fight... did someone say something they thought was okay but could be perceived as not (and they're confused about why it's not) - that's where moderators come in - using human judgement calls. AI isn't there yet.

Comment: (if you used Grammarly to write your actual answer - I'd be worried about using it at all)

Comment: @JonClements I 100% agree on judgemental areas and importance of moderator there. But, regarding simple grammar checks, I feel, we don't need a 3rd person[as mod] to intervene and correct because English borrowed many cultural words and differences exist. yes,  tools work as instructed, color is not colour and labor is not labour, simply depends on where you from.(this is why no human, tool sets the standard of communication) After all isn't it the beauty of communication(even there are differences).

Comment: for this context: just like to know "what will be the  new mod efforts to bring in simplicity and better standards to SO, where he himself no more needed as a watchman" even simple way.."How many areas he will convert as not a mod task by next election"

Comment: Sure... but the tool you were promoting as to grammar didn't quite work and another user that has editing privileges edited your post to be correct. There's no issue here... a diamond moderator has different roles than necessarily having to edit people's posts. Seems the system works fine to me?

Comment: No, Neither "promoting" nor endorsing Grammarly, But referencing it as a possibility for SO to come up with own grammar tool solution. Questioned, new moderator's interest in such a solution than doing manual edits.

Comment: the diamond moderators aren't the one that do edits though... a non-mod user corrected your post here (for its grammar) using a system you proposed could be a tool for promoting correct grammar? Do you not see the irony/inconsistency of your suggestion?

Comment: while I thank yivi to correct grammar, I am worried how you missed fact that we have been communicating long before that edit happened and it has negligible effect in discussion .without undermining yivi's work,such corrections are a time-waste to me and yivi when no impact to communication.finally yes I recommend steps towards auto solution (build/borrow) or no correction and my personal view  remains  'no human time in correcting' as they are no less error-prone in understanding another person view than a machine without having the same background.

Comment: You seem to be continuing to miss the point that moderators are not elected as spelling/grammar checkers.

Comment: Also, we are building a high quality repository of knowledge. If one understands language and its role in such an endeavor, one wouldn't devalue the edits for 'minor things' like capitalization.  In any case I don't see how that is the mod's responsibilities. The developers of stack? Maybe. The owners of some scripts as charcoal or smoke detector? Sure. Not elected volunteers who volunteered to do 'human moderation'. Your question is similar to asking a limo driver 'what are you doing to help self driving cars'.

Answer (score -23):

A question is flagged as a duplicate.

The question has already been marked as a duplicate by vote at the time a moderator sees the user pointing out how it's not a dupe.  The user has not edited the question.  The user points out the non-duplicate nature of the question in a comment explaining how precisely it is not a duplicate.  What action do you take?

Comment: Users often get it wrong.  Are we sure the user has properly understood the duplicate, and isn't just looking for a personalized answer?

Comment: Moderators generally don't handle close flags, to my knowledge. They are largely handled by normal users in the close vote queue. Duplicate flags in particular require domain knowledge, and I would expect them to shy away from those even more as a general rule.

Comment: If the user edits the question to clarify why it is not a duplicate, that gets handled by domain experts in the reopen queue. Flagging this for moderator attention is invalid.

Comment: Flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention.

Comment: This question is missing a lot of assumptions and context. For example, has the question already been marked as a duplicate by vote at the time a moderator sees the user pointing out how it's not a dupe? Did the user edit their question, or did they point it out in a comment (because they didn't know how to edit their question, or because they didn't see a need to)? Or did the user point it out in a moderator-attention flag after the fact (and how long)? A question goes through several different stages in its lifetime and what action a mod should take, if any, depends on the circumstances.

Answer (score -24):

I would like to ask about close voting. Sometimes is really hard to select is this post "unclear" or "too broad" and many users do not use button "skip". Do you agree with Community to close a question or reject their decision or may be you close / reopen question by your own?

Comment: This question is not at all clear to me. Are you intending to ask prospective moderator candidates whether they would close and re-open a question to change between "unclear' and "too broad" close reasons? How could that distinction *possibly* matter to anyone?

Comment: Somewhat ironically, I would vote-close this question as "unclear".