# Should staff be commenting on non-answers to their own questions instead of deleting them?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-answers, not-an-answer, stack-exchange-team

I just noticed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59757435/11107541#comment135279505_76732784):

> Hey Tim, sorry to nitpick, but answers are for solutions to the original problem. If you have an additional question, they're better left as a comment (50 rep) or an entirely new question (1 rep)

I personally don't think it's an enormous problem if that staff eventually goes and deletes it after a week or so, but it just strikes me as... weird, considering that in the low quality queue, the similar canned comment accompanies a form of a *delete-vote* vote. Is this a good/okay thing for someone with mod powers to do?

I didn't initially notice this, but the answer is to a question by that same staff, so I can understand if this particular case is due to a conflict of interest, but they could just as well have another staff delete it.

Comment: It’s not the first time, staff, has chosen the incorrect moderator option during the strike. It probably won’t be the last time.

Comment: @SecurityHound [yes, I am aware](/q/425587/11107541)

Comment: Maybe they simply refrained from deleting due to a [conflict of interest](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338469/is-it-possible-for-a-moderator-to-handle-flags-on-their-own-posts/338472#338472)? Note that the question the answer is posted on is posted by the staff member.

Comment: If the staff member has flagged it as NAA and left the comment, I see no problem with that.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat - If SE staff are going to moderate then they have to moderate. They can’t just pick and choose what they moderate

Comment: @SecurityHound I am quite sure even the moderators don't handle flags and let other moderators handle them in case of conflict of interest. If we are upholding the staff to standards we have for moderators let's not pick and choose what standards apply there.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat - They are more community moderators than staff. Furthermore, the question was self-answered 3 years ago; I don't see how a non-answer answer submitted by a user and flagged by a community user shouldn't be handled properly instead of a staff member acting as a moderator.

Answer (score 6):

I believe that users with power to unilaterally delete content (diamond community mods and staff with mod permissions) should not use those powers on their own posts<sup>*</sup> due to real or perceived conflict of interests.

This particular case is self-answered question by staff member that also commented on non-answer. There is absolutely nothing in the "answer" that called for some sort of an immediate action (no rude/illegal content) - regular NAA flag should be enough in that case. I don't even think directly asking other mods to review would be appropriate in this situation as there is zero urgency to it.

At this point the answer is deleted by community users (due to this post) which is even better outcome from mods' time usage point of view.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup>I except some exceptional cases when an immediate action is required even on their own posts - outrageously rude content or posts that likely be a legal trouble.</sub>

Comment: I _generally_ agree with this, although I'd probably still do it in cases like this where the right solution is _so obvious_ as to not be within reasonable debate.  Though as a moderator, I probably have a lot more insight into where that line is than a non-moderator does.

Comment: @RyanM-Regenerateresponse NAA is NAA. NAA is quite clear, and clearly to be deleted, because it’s NAA. I don’t think you have much more insight into this obviousness than any other user, just because you’re a moderator.

Comment: @Andreas good point.  I probably should have said "than someone who isn't actively involved in site curation or moderation."